# Comparing variances of multiple correlated variables

Tags: r, correlation, variance

I am trying to find a way to compare the variances of multiple variables in the same sample. More specifically, I have a sample of 118 participants who completed eight items (on the same 0-100 response scale), and I would like to test if the sample variances on these eight items are significantly different from one another.

In my attempt to find a formal answer to this, I have tried to apply suggestions from two papers (see below). However, I guess I assumed that the comparison of correlated variances is more common, and I am afraid I might be missing something. Does anyone have an idea how to approach this issue? Also, does anyone know if a function to do this is implemented in one of the R packages already? Thank you in advance!

Papers:

Cohen, A. (1986). Comparing variances of correlated variables. Psychometrika, 51(3), 379-391.

Cohen, A. (1990). Graphical methods for testing the equality of several correlated variances. Journal of the Royal Statistical Society: Series D (The Statistician), 39(1), 43-52.